# Value Counter / Calculator

Tags: php

I would like to achieve the following: I have a variable A with a value from 1 - 1000. For every 100 the value reaches, a second variable B should get added +1. A third variable C should echo all number of variable A which are less than 100

For example:

```
$a = 10
$b = 0
$c = 10

$a = 100
$b = 1
$c = 00

$a = 110
$b = 1
$c = 10

$a = 1530
$b = 15
$c = 30
```

What's the best way to achieve that in PHP? Use str_split() oder count()?

Comment: Use [`range`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.range.php)

Comment: Could you give me an example? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$b = floor($a/100);
$c = $a % 100;
echo 'wow, that was easy';
```